# diffrent return value for same arguement of ceil() function

Tags: c++17, ceil

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int ans = ceil(1.5);
    printf("%d\n", ans);

    ans = ceil(3 / 2);
    printf("%d", ans);
}
```

**Output:**
2 
1

Why this code print different answers in my editor (vs code)?

Comment: 3/2 = 1 not 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your are sending different arguments to function `ceil`

`3 / 2` will be first calculated to integer `1`, for `3` and `2` are all integers so the operator `/` will return an integer.

So you are actually calling `ceil(1)` for the second time

Answer (score 0):

When u sent 3/2 as an argument, you are actually sent 1. The program calculates 3/2 as an int therefore the result is 1, and then the second ans calculation is actually by ceil(1.0)

Instead ceil(3 / 2), you need to do ceil(3.0 / 2.0). In this situation, the program calculates this as a double and the result will be 1.5, meaning the second ans calculation is by ceil(1.5).

Comment: Is it possible to send 3 / 2 as an argument so that ceil use it as 1.5 instead of 1?

Comment: Yes, as I said, do ceil(3.0 / 2.0).